# Does not exist in the namespace?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello I am having trouble with a namespace issue.

[image: Problem]

So the namespace is correct, even typing I can autofill with the correct namespace as seen here:

[[image: Autofill[2]]

**What I have tried**:

- Cleaning Solution
- Rebuilding Solution (Errors out)
- Closing VS and reopening
- Closing solution and reopening

All this has come to no avail. Thank you for reading

Comment: Did you try deleting the obj and bin folders?

Comment: I have not, I just changed the namespace to testing123 and it decided to work doing that?

Comment: Same solution? It's not an external Lib with different .Net version?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/pwwpyc this is what I did for it to work. Still don't know why I had to rename the namespace

Comment: What if you try in your xml Getting&#95;annoyed&#95;with&#95;views.ViewModel ?

Comment: Did you check project .net version which contains that object. I have same experiences before It was reason of wrong .net version reference. And compiler was see reference but cannot compile real object.

Comment: I honestly have no idea why this was downvoted, but I did check it honestly just renaming the namespace worked?

Comment: Not a reason why someone would downvote the question, but renaming your namespace should never be a required solution for this type problem. I would suggest doing what @ShakHam mentioned and delete all of the `obj` and `bin` folders throughout your solution to make sure stale builds are gone. This has fixed most odd behaviors in VS when it comes to build errors and some runtime issues.

Comment: Solved, thank you!